# Who can explain the strange result when I use Module names in nested modules in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I found this code produced unexpected result:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmodule Foo.Bar do
    def test1 do
      IO.inspect Foo.Baz
    end
    def test2 do
      IO.inspect Other.Baz
    end
  end
end
> Foo.Foo.Bar.test1
Foo.Foo.Baz
> Foo.Foo.Bar.test2
Other.Baz
```

I expect the tests should produce consistent results at least, like:

```
# Both have a namespace of Foo
> Foo.Foo.Bar.test1
Foo.Foo.Baz
> Foo.Foo.Bar.test2
Foo.Other.Baz
# or
# Neither has a namespace of Foo
> Foo.Foo.Bar.test1
Foo.Baz
> Foo.Foo.Bar.test2
Other.Baz
```

But the unexpected result shows that it depends on prefixes of module names(`Foo.Bar` & `Foo.Baz` in test1), which is surprising for me.

**UPDATE:**

*I realize there's another problem thanks to the answer of @mudasobwa*

For this situation, we know `B` should be `A.B` because we want to use `B` directly:

```
defmodule A do
  defmodule B do
    def test do
      IO.inspect B
    end
  end
end
> A.B.test
A.B
```

But for this, why is `B` still `A.B`?

```
defmodule A do
  defmodule B.C do
    def test do
      IO.inspect B
    end
  end
end
> A.B.C.test
A.B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `Foo.Baz` and `Other.Baz` are *atoms*. Just simple atoms and the ability to write them with fancy dots and capitalized is nothing but the syntactic sugar. Try to open `IEx` and *loading nothing* just type:

```
iex(1)> i Foo.Baz
```

the result would be: `IEx` is aware of it, and it is an atom:

```
iex(1)> i Foo.Baz

Term
  Foo.Baz
Data type
  Atom
Reference modules
  Atom
```

That said, you output atoms and they are successfully output. The fact that they look similar to modules’ names is an occasion.

---

But since this is used as a module name representation, Elixir tries to do it’s best to “resolve” those. Being “inside module,” one might call a module function from inside other module function without prefixing it with module name:

```
defmodule A do
  def a, do: IO.puts "Hello"
  def b, do: a  # ⇐ this
end
```

Here `a` is implicitly resolved to `A.a` when called from `A.b`. The same happens for embedded/nested modules:

```
defmodule A do
  defmodule B do
    def a, do: IO.puts "Hello"
    def b, do: B.a  # ⇐ this
  end
end
```

To make this `B.a` call possible, `B.a` is in fact being resolved to `A.B.a`, which is possible because `B` inside itself is resolved to `A.B`.

What you see is a drawback of this atom to module name extrapolation.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with OP's question.

Comment: @Dogbert indeed, thanks, for some reason yesterday I published the half of the answer; I thought it makes it clear, but now I reread it and have the explanation updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I thought of another problem related to this. I've updated the question.

Comment: `B` is obviously resolved to `A.B` because it’s resolved to the full-qualified module name, not to “this,” or to what you have expected. `B` in that context is `A.B`. I am afraid I don’t understand what you have expected to see there instead.

Comment: I understand your example. But for my example `A.B.C.test`, I thought `B.C` is a whole so I `B` should not be `A.B`. However, from the result, what I thought is totally wrong.

Comment: Think of module names as of breadcrumbs. There is no “solidness,” `defmodule A.B do` is a syntactic sugar to write `defmodule A do defmodule B do`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a better way to thinking about this problem.